# Azure ADLS Gen2 not available

Tags: hdfs, azure-data-lake

I am trying to create an Storage v2 Account with Data Lake Gen2 preview, but it is disabled from the Azure Wizard. 
As far as I have read it should be available for this setup?
[image: adls gen2 wizard]
[image: adls gen2 wizard]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can now specifiy that you want to use a hierarchical namespace at the creation of the storage account (via the portal in the advanced tab).

At the time the question has been raised it was in a gated preview, see the following [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/data-lake-storage/quickstart-create-account). You had to fill out a [preview survey](https://forms.office.com/Pages/ResponsePage.aspx?id=v4j5cvGGr0GRqy180BHbR1SQ6sl4CPhFmtLCLnOIR11UMlQ2TTYwS1FOUUhUTFI0UzgzUEc0NFpWMy4u) to get your subscription whitelisted for this feature.